# how to get a dropdownlist value in the same view in yii2

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii2

I have a dropdownlist in a activeform like this

```
<?=   $form->field($model, 'emailTemplateId')->dropDownList($emailTemplateIds,
                                   ['prompt'=>'-Choose an Email Template-']   
?>
```

and I want to send its selected value in below link's parameter.

Like this:

```
<?= Html::a('Send', ['invoice/send-invoice', 'emailTemplateId' => $emailTemplateIds] ) ?>
```

How its done?

Comment: Use from jquery (select option value and send it to your link) . Jquery help link : https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

Comment: in action, I'm receiving nothing

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery to do this

```
<?=   $form->field($model, 'emailTemplateId')->dropDownList($emailTemplateIds,
                               ['prompt'=>'-Choose an Email Template-', 'id'=>'select']   
  ?>

  <?= Html::a('Send', ['invoice/send-invoice', 'emailTemplateId' => 0], ['id' => 'send'] ) ?>

 jQuery Part

$("#select").change(function(){
    var text = $("#send").attr("href");
    href = text.replace(/(emailTemplateId=)[^\&]+/, '$1' + $(this).val());
    $("#send").attr("href", href);
})
```